# $post->comment_status always returns 'closed'

Tags: comments

I don't know why, but some of my old posts are always closed. Even if status in `wp_posts` set to `open`, `$post->comment_status` returns `closed`. I setup some plugins before, which disable comments, but now all this plugins removed.

Any suggestion, what happened?

Comment: There's a setting to close comments after certain time in Settings->Discussion

Comment: @Hannes, this checkbox is checked, but some posts are still with disabled comments